# How to save users markers from leaflet.js in database?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, leaflet

I'm using leaflet.js to make users add their markers on a map. And I want to save the latitude and longitude in my database.

I've got the DB with 3 columns (markerid ; lat ; lng) but I'm new to PHP and ajax and I really couldn't figure out how to send marker infos to DB and retrieve them after on users map.

If anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a front end framework? (i.e. Angular, React, etc.)